Are slurs necessary for a piano tremolo, and if so what does their presence indicate?


The two quotations above differ only in that the octave tremolo for the left hand has a slur.  I've seen tremolos in piano music both with and without the slur.  How would a pianist perform the two measures differently?

The slur is just there for visual clarity (optically bracketing the otherwise isolated parts), since there aren't beams joining the notes.

So, were the tremolo of half this value and beamed, it would be unnecessary?

@nuggethead Yes. Sometimes half-notes are beamed in a tremolo.

Notations like this can happen in string notation to make clear that the tremolo is to be played on one bow, and can also be used as phrasing slur, to indicate emphasis. In the first place this is a pretty weird notation in piano music. While most other instruments use between note tremolo, on piano you tend to get beamed notes with different note heads (and floating beams for smaller values). A whole note tremolo would then be usually notated like this:

And here you’ll find that there is a clear difference between this (being read as an even tremolo for one measure) and something like

rather indicating two half note beats of tremolo.
